# CSS to hide area around search box in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, css

I'm styling a SharePoint 2013 site and am having trouble targeting an area beneath the search box. From the image, you can see what I'm after. The green highlight on the left is what I want to change colors on (to be the light blue you see to the left).

That div has no id to target. How can I access it? I tried a few things that appear to do nothing. Is my syntax off?

## titleAreaRow .ms-tableCell .ms-verticalAlignTop { background-color: #dae3f3; }

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn proper CSS:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

If you add spaces in a CSS selector, that means you want a child of

so it is:

```
titleAreaRow .ms-tableCell.ms-verticalAlignTop
```

and not

```
titleAreaRow .ms-tableCell .ms-verticalAlignTop
```